# Setter using different type in java

Tags: java, spring, setter, value-type

I need to write a setter for an array using spring's value annotation so it will come from properties file.

```
private String[] aList;

public String[] getAList()
{
return aList;
}

@value("a:b")
public String[] setAList(String aString)
{
aList = aString.Split(":");
}
```

I am not sure if this is the right way to do?

Will I get the right value from string?

Thanks,

Comment: Why don't you run it and report back?

Answer (score 1):

Always have the same type for getter and setter pairs. In order to perform what you want, you could simply rename setAList to setAListAsColonSeparatedValues or something similar. Also, your setter method should return void.

Answer (score 0):

If you put them in your properties file as

```
listItems=1,2,3,4,5,6
```

Spring will load an array for you

```
@Value( "${listItems}")
  private String[] aList;
```

If iterate through aList you get

item = 1
item = 2
item = 3